# Example of a symmetric manifold without rotation symmetry?

Tags: manifolds, symmetry

Consider a flat torus, in 2D. It has translation symmetry but not rotational symmetry.

Are there any manifolds that are not simply products like $S_1 \times S_1$ that **do not** have rotational symmetry but have either translational or a combination of a translation plus a rotation in their symmetry?

*Edit*: In other words a symmetric manifold with **no** rigid symmetries in which one point is fixed. (Would they all be flat?)

For example what about the projective plane or, homology sphere? What symmetries do those have?

Comment: Can you be more precise?  I guess by manifold you mean Riemannian manifold?  Then you can define a rotation as an isometry that fixes a point and is orientation-preserving at that point, but what do you mean by translation?

Comment: Basically what I mean is, a manifold in which there is no symmetry where you fix a point and do a rotation, but does have symmetry where you transport the point to another point. e.g. a sphere has rotational symmetry, but a flat torus doesn't. Maybe think of it as tranporting a little vector. Rotate a vector on a sphere and it's still the same.

Comment: What about a Klein bottle?

Comment: Even with your comment, you notion of a translation symmetry is undefined. "transporting a little vector" is not a mathematical concept. Each rotation of the sphere also "transports one point to another". Maybe what you mean is that a translation is an isometry that has no fixed points? Then, do you regard the map $v\mapsto -v$ of the sphere to itself as a translation? It has no fixed points on the sphere.

Comment: Exactly no fixed points.

Comment: OK, then every round sphere has a symmetry without fixed points. And spheres are not flat. For more examples, think about hyperbolic spaces. These are not flat either.  There is entire area of geometry which deals with "homogeneous spaces". Most of these admit translations in your sense.

Comment: Yes but a sphere is excluded because it *does* have a symmetry with a fixed point. I'm looking for geometries that don't.

Comment: @Jason DeVito. Yes, I think a Klein bottle would work. Good point.

Comment: Actually, flat Klein bottles do have symmetries with fixed points. However, every compact oriented surface of genus $\ge 3$ admits a hyperbolic metric such that all nontrivial symmetries have no fixed points.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan. Would these bese continous symmetries or discrete? Could you put this as the answer maybe? (I presume these are 2D surfaces.)

Comment: I am not quite ready for answering since I do not completely understand your question. In this example the group of symmetries is finite. Are you interested in  locally homogeneous metrics? Homogeneous metrics? (I.e. the isometry group acts transitively.) Also, when you say "one point is fixed", do you mean "at least one point" or "exactly one point"? For instance, if an isometry of $S^2$ fixes one point, it fixes at least two points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to interpret your question.

It appears that for a Riemannian manifold $M$ a "translation" of $M$ is an isometry $\phi: M\to M$ which is either the identity or has no fixed points in $M$. Then to say that the isometry group of $M$ consists only of "translations" amounts to saying that the isometry group $Isom(M)$ of $M$ acts freely. (The latter is the standard terminology.)

Boring examples where $Isom(M)$ acts freely are when $Isom(M)$ is trivial, i.e. consists only of the identity element. One can prove that a "generic" Riemannian metric on a given manifold (of dimension $\ge 2$) has trivial group of isometries. For instance, for (connected) surfaces $M$ this comes from the fact one can prescribe the Gaussian curvature of the Riemannian metric $M$  (subject to some sign conditions). See [this wikipdeai article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescribed_scalar_curvature_problem) for details and references.

A generic choice of such a function allows no (non-identity) diffeomorphisms $\phi: M\to M$ which preserve the function $K$ (i.e. $K\circ \phi=\phi$).

One can promote this to more interesting examples where $Isom(M)$ is nontrivial but acts freely. For instance, start with the projective plane $P=RP^2$, choose a generic curvature function $K(x)>0$ on $P$ and take the corresponding Riemannian metric $g$. Now, lift $g$ to a metric $\tilde{g}$ on the universal covering of $P$, which is $M\sim S^2$. Then $(M, \tilde{g})$ has a nontrivial isometry (order two involution $\tau$ generating the deck-transformation group of the covering $M\to P$). With a bit more work one verifies that $Isom(M,\tilde{g})=\langle\tau\rangle= \{id, \tau\}$. Thus,    $Isom(M,\tilde{g})$ acts freely on $M$.

One can, however, ask for more, namely, that $M$ is **homogeneous**, i.e. the isometry group of $M$ acts freely and transitively (i.e. simply transitively). Such examples exist in dimension 3, they are called **Berger spheres**. Berger spheres are homogenous Riemannian manifolds diffeomorphic to $S^3$ (the 3-dimensional sphere). These manifolds come with some parameters.

In Theorem 4.1 in

P. Gadea, J. Oubiña, [Homogeneous Riemannian Structures on
Berger 3-Spheres](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9761/b26db00f655cecfd00771db925d6cba74135.pdf), Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society, 48 (2005), no. 2, 375–387.

the authors prove that for certain values of parameters of the Berger sphere $M$, its isometry group acts simply transitively on $M$. (The group is isomorphic to $SU(2)$.)

The manifolds in these examples are definitely not products and the metric is not flat. (Actually, a sphere of dimension $\ge 2$ admits no flat metric.)

**Edit.** One more thing: In geometry a "symmetric space" (or a manifold) usually means something different from the header of your post, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space). To make it more confusing, in topology, a "[symmetric product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology))" means yet something else.